# javascript log json object with pretty format

Tags: javascript, logging, console.log

I'm using a lot `console.log` for debugging purpose. When I log long objects, it is difficult to read the complete object. Is there a `console.pretty` or something to print the data in a pretty way?

Actual (logs inline): 
`{data:'data',data1:'data1'}`

Expect:

```
{
  data:'data',
  data1:'data1'
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

The third parameter passed will be the number of spaces to indent the members.

```js
var obj = {
  data: 'data',
  data1: 'data1'
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 2));
```

---

If you need this more often, you can also define a function on window object

```js
// Define on global window object
window.console.prettyPrint = function() {
  // Loop over arguments, so any number of objects can be passed
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments[i], 0, 2));
  }
};

var obj = {
  data: 'data',
  data1: 'data1'
};

var myObj = {
  hello: 'World!'
};

console.prettyPrint(obj, myObj);
```